# Get strtotime to find next timestamp at given time

Tags: php, timestamp, strtotime

I'm trying to make strtotime give me a timestamp, but I only know that it's a hour and minute and it's the next in the row. Fx.

If the given hour and minute is 01:00 (AM) I require it to return the timestamp of 01:00 (AM), if it is the day before at 19:00, I would like it to return the timestamp of 01:00 the next day, but if it is after midnight at 00:30, it should return the timestamp 01:00 the same date.

To simplify it, it's the NEXT occurrence of a time.

Strtotime is giving me the time on the same day, if and not the next occurrence.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the code you tried? There are a few ways that PHP handles date/time, so it'd be helpful to see which direction you took.

Comment: `$start = strtotime("next ".$_POST['starttime']);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily generate a timestamp, see if it's already past, and then increment the day.

Something like this perhaps?

```
$timestamp = strtotime("1:00 am");
if($timestamp < time()) {
    $timestamp = strtotime("+1 day",$timestamp);
}
```

Or if you want to tighten it up to a one-liner:

```
$string = "1:00 am";
$timestamp = (strtotime($string) > time()) ? strtotime($string) : strtotime("tomorrow " . $string);
```

Comment: But what if we passed midnight? Then it returns the correct timestamp without adding 1 day.

Comment: Guess I'm don't understand the question. If it's Tuesday 4pm, this solution will give you Wednesday 1am. And if it's Wednesday 12:30am, this solution will still give you Wednesday 1am. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @RoboForm Give me an example where this solution is failing to provide what you want, not sure I see it.